# How to call $emit in Pinia's $onAction callback using Options API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Is it possible to make this work or must I use the composition API?
I also tried to move the $onAction call in a watcher and it works sort of, but maybe it's a bad idea?

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const someStore = useSomeStore();

    someStore.$onAction(() => {
        this.$emit(...) // "this" is undefined
    });

    return { someStore };
  },
}
```